# Parse date in Android (DatabaseHelper.java)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, parsing, sql-insert

I've got an annoying problem with my dates.
I want to convert my string (which I get from a textView) into a date format.
Sadly my parsing keeps throwing me errors.

This is the code:

```
public void submitExpenseButton_click(View v){
EditText editDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateNewExpense);
            String date = editDate.getText().toString();

Finance finance = new Finance();
finance.setDate(Date.valueOf(date));
db.insertIncome(finance);
}
```

Everytime I try to insert a record I get the following error in my errorlog:
[image]

Could anybody tell me how to fix this? I'm out of clue's here.
For further reference I've included my class, so you know how the getters and setters work too.

finance.class:

```
public class Finance {
    private Date date;

public Finance(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public long insertIncome(Finance finance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("date", String.valueOf(finance.getDate()));
        long id = db.insert("finance", null, values);

        db.close();
        return id;
    }
```

NOTE: I stripped out the other fields! I do have id's etc in that db.. I left them out to reduce text.
So what is the correct way for parsing / formatting / ..?

Thanks
Yenthe

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use something like this, which is a standard way we convert dates in java:

```
String dateText = editDate.getText().toString()
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy").parse(dateText);
```

Be sure to use the correct format string so it matches what is in your edit field.

More detail here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

To convert the Date to a sql Date, which is a different object, just do this:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Okay that did sort the error problems for inserting. Now I can't seem to find a format in those docs for DD-MM-YYYY? I'd like the dates to be like 16/11/2013 for today, for example.
Also, a second question.. in my DatabaseHelper I have     finance.setDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(cursor.getString(4))); which now seems to cause an error. How would I fix that one?

Comment: You have to use those letters in the docs. So you would want "dd-MM-YYYY". Don't use valueOf on Date. Instead, parse the string to a Date like in my response. That will be a java.util.Date and not a java.sql.Date. But you can convert between them with the "long". I updated my answer to show how.

Comment: Small correction, I think you need "dd/MM/YYYY" for the format if you want "16/11/2013".

Comment: Both dd/MM/YYYY and dd/MM/YYY do not seem to be supported, as my app crashes on both sadly.. and I'm going to try the sql convert now too

Comment: I would recommend you find out exactly why your app is crashing and work from there. It appears you are guessing the cause is the format, but your stack trace suggests it could be a null date. In any case, you need to know the exact reason for the failure. Good luck!